# Python: parallel processing while yielding

Tags: python, multiprocessing, yield

I am creating a generator of the lines in a list of files, my approach is something like:

```
def load(f_name: str):
    with open(f_name, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    # some calculations
    return lines

def iter_files(f_names: list):
    for f in f_names:
        for line in load(f):
            yield line
```

What I would like to do, if possible and useful, is to load the next file while yielding on another.
Being completely new to multiprocessing I tried the following:

```
cache = dict()

def load(f_name: str, id: int):
    global cache
    with open(f_name, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    # some calculations
    cache[id] = lines

def iter_list(arr):
    for x in arr:
        yield x

def iter_files(f_names: list):
    global cache
    num_files = len(f_names)
    load(f_names[0], 0)
    for n in range(num_files - 1):
        current = mp.Process(target=iter_list, args=(cache[n],))
        next = mp.Process(target=load, args=(f_names[n + 1], n + 1))
        current.start()
        next.start()
        current.join()
        next.join()
        del cache[n]
    iter_list(cache[num_files - 1])
    del cache[num_files - 1]
```

But besides looking overly complicated, its not working.

First if I don't put the main code into an 'if __name__ == "__main__":' (which I would rather not be mandatory) I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError:
      An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
      current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
```

But even if I do the files are not added to the cache:

```
current = mp.Process(target=iter_list, args=(cache[n],))
KeyError: 1
```

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all

Comment: "What I would like to do, if possible and useful". Possible, sure. Useful? It depends what you are doing with these lines. If the amount of processing is small compared to the I/O (which could easily be 100 times slower), you won't see any significant speedups from the additional complexity.

Comment: @Thomas files are quite small (50kB on average), but they are encoded such that each byte corresponds more or less to an entry of the processed list, so I guess the slow part of the loading algrithm is the '# some calculations' and not the actual reding of the files.

Answer (score 1):

The `multiprocessing.Queue` class is ideal for this. You `put` the lines in at one end (the subprocess) and `get` them back at the other end (the main process). Unfortunately there's no built-in way to mark the queue as "finished" so we need to `put` a sentinel value like `None` to indicate that all lines have been processed.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def load(f_name: str):
    with open(f_name, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    # some calculations
    return lines

def iter_files(f_names: list, queue: mp.Queue):
    for f in f_names:
        for line in load(f):
            queue.put(line)
    queue.put(None)

def iter_files_process(f_names: list):
    queue = mp.Queue()
    process = mp.Process(target=iter_files, args=(f_names, queue))
    process.start()
    while True:
        line = queue.get()
        if line is None:  # End-of-queue value.
            break
        yield line
    process.join()  # Wait for the process to be completely finished.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for line in iter_files_process(['a.txt', 'b.txt']):
        print(line, end='')
```

Comment: When I do queue.get() the value gets deleted from the queue, right? Also, in this way the process tries to load all the files, is there a way to limit it to the next one only (and the current one if not already in the queue)?

Comment: Yes, `queue.get()` removes and returns the next item. You can pass a maximum queue size to the `Queue()` constructor to prevent your file reader process from getting too far ahead (e.g. `queue = mp.Queue(1)`).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution offered by Thomas is an interesting approach, however:

1. A `Pipe`, although a less flexible construct then a `Queue`, is all that is required here since there is only a single sender and a single receiver and it is much more performant.
2. I tested with both using multithreading and multiprocessing and multithreading is also much faster.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pipe
from multiprocessing.connection import Connection
import threading

def load(f_name: str):
    with open(f_name, "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    # some calculations
    return lines

def iter_files(f_names: list, send_conn: Connection):
    for f in f_names:
        for line in load(f):
            send_conn.send(line)
    send_conn.send(None)

def generate_lines(f_names: list):
    recv_conn, send_conn = Pipe(False)
    threading.Thread(target=iter_files, args=(f_names, send_conn), daemon=True).start()
    for line in iter(recv_conn.recv, None):
        yield line

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time

    t = time.time()
    lines = list(generate_lines(['irv.py', 'waitList.py', 'send_mail_async.py', '../ajaxtcr.js', '../browser_detection.php']))
    elapsed = time.time() - t
    print(len(lines), elapsed)
```

Prints:

```
6537 0.18297886848449707
```

Note that Thomas' code unmodified except for adding the *encoding* argument to the `open` call took for this file list 0.24300265312194824 seconds.

But compare with the original code:

```py
def load(f_name: str):
    with open(f_name, "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    # some calculations
    return lines

def iter_files(f_names: list):
    for f in f_names:
        for line in load(f):
            yield line

import time
t = time.time()
lines = list(iter_files(['irv.py', 'waitList.py', 'send_mail_async.py', '../ajaxtcr.js', '../browser_detection.php']))
elapsed = time.time() - t
print(len(lines), elapsed)
```

Prints:

```
6537 0.07400083541870117
```

So this approach offers no real improvement. Another approach is to process *all* of the files *concurrently*:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def load(f_name: str):
    with open(f_name, "r", encoding='utf8') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    # some calculations
    return lines

def generate_lines(f_names: list):
    with ThreadPool(len(f_names)) as pool:
        for lines in pool.imap(load, f_names):
            for line in lines:
                yield line

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time

    t = time.time()
    lines = list(generate_lines(['irv.py', 'waitList.py', 'send_mail_async.py', '../ajaxtcr.js', '../browser_detection.php']))
    elapsed = time.time() - t
    print(len(lines), elapsed)
```

Prints:

```
6537 0.010999441146850586
```

**Important Note**

Granted that there could be contention when going against multiple files concurrently and the reason why performance was *so* good in this last benchmark was because that all or most of the data being read was probably in cache because these files have been read so many times from all these tests. The solution with the Pipe (or Queue) is using the same cache and clearly performs worse than the original code, so the only real question is whether thread pool version will perform better on un-cached data.

I would have to wait now a significant amount of time (or reboot?) to be sure that the cache has been flushed and then rerun the thread pool example to get a more accurate reading. Or use a new file list with the thread pool code and then run the original code, which will have the advantage of caching and compare.

**Update**

I reran this with another list of files and the thread pool solution performed worse than the original code. **I would just stick with the original code and avoid any attempts to incorporate multithreading, multiprocessing or asyncio in an attempt to improve performance.**

Depending on what the "some calculations" referred to in function `load` are, you might consider:

```py
def load(f_name: str):
    with open(f_name, "r" as f:
        for line in f:
            # some calculations
            yield line

def iter_files(f_names: list):
    for f in f_names:
        yield from load(f)
```

This would save memory resources.